# How to install Vizdoom python

Tags: python, visual-studio, windows-10, reinforcement-learning

I am new to programming, I am trying to install vizdoom on windows 10, python. Using the command:

> ```
> pip install vizdoom
> ```

and keep getting this error, I have tried searching around, have spent hours but am not able to fix it.

```
Collecting vizdoom   Using cached vizdoom-1.1.7.tar.gz (4.9 MB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe'
-c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-sqhbgmz4\\vizdoom\\setup.py'"'"';
__file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-sqhbgmz4\\vizdoom\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-m7e2idad'
         cwd: C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-sqhbgmz4\vizdoom\
    Complete output (5 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-sqhbgmz4\vizdoom\setup.py", line 14, in <module>
        raise RuntimeError("Building pip package on Windows is not currently available ...")    
    RuntimeError: Building pip package on Windows is not currently available ...
    ---------------------------------------- ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full  command output.
```

as a last resort, I hope to get some help from here.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I switched to ubuntu.